# Is there any short phrase or sentence available to tell that someone was always hiding one's mistakes

Tags: word-usage, phrases, vocabulary, sentence

I wonder if there is any phrase or sentence available out there to express that someone was always hiding or taking care of one's mistakes and silly things;
to tell them that one is highly obliged.

Answer (score 1):

**[cover for someone/something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cover-for-someone-something)**

> — phrasal verb with *cover* US ​
>   /ˈkʌv·ər/ verb
>   ​to provide an excuse for someone, or an explanation for something that has gone wrong:
>   *She would cover for her brothers when they came in late.*

Answer (score 0):

> You've always been there **to cover my back**. That's really appreciated.

Using *cover **my** back* as a variant of *cover your back* which is someone protecting themselves from negative consequences:

> cover your back BRITISH, AMERICAN or cover your ass AMERICAN, RUDE
>
> If you do something in order to cover your back, you do it in order to protect yourself, for example against criticism or against accusations of doing something wrong. *He had covered his back by persuading Evans, chairman of their finance committee, to provide a written approval for the contract*. *Newspaper editors have to cover their backs against accusations of libel*.
>
> *Source: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/covered+my+back)*

Answer (score -3):

You can say "you have been covering me up always, I'm highly obliged to you."

Comment: the phrase is "covering up for me"

Comment: Also, *always* doesn't go at the end of a phrase in most (all?) dialects of English. It always precedes the verb it modifies.